# Should Maybe's be used to hold error messages?

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

I have a Haskell function which takes user input and another function which validates this input. Of course, the validation could fail, in which case I would like to return an error message giving some feedback on what was done incorrectly.

I know that there are many ways that I could do this. After the little experience I have, it seems like the best way is to use `Either String a`. What is throwing me off is that I don't care about the `a`. Either it fails and I would like to store more information, or it succeeds. The `a` is wasted.

**Is using `Maybe String` an acceptable way to store an error message?** It feels backwards to me, but completely ignoring the value in the right of an `Either` feels pretty bad too. What is canonical here?

Comment: It sounds like the code you're writing includes some antipatterns (in this case, possibly side-effectful code). You should generally care about _either_ value of an `Either` value (no pun or confusion intended) -- that is to say that in both the `Left` and `Right` cases should be handled appropriately.

Comment: @Jules I agree that I should care about either side of the `Either`, which is why I was thinking that using `Maybe` was the way to go. Are you saying that user input is the antipattern?

Comment: Semantically your validation function may return an error message, or return no error message, so it looks totally reasonable to to use `Maybe` for its return type. It's not the "error message" vs "correct result" pattern which `Either` usually implies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I encourage the use of `Except String ()` (or `Either String ()`) over `Maybe String`, for a few reasons:

- You will probably find later that your it is convenient for your validation function to return some parts of the data structure. For example, while validating that a `String` is a phone number, you might want to return the area code, first, and second parts of the number, giving a validation type like `String -> Except String (Int, Int, Int)` or similar. Making validators that don't return anything interesting have type `Foo -> Except String ()` makes them just a special case of this pattern -- and therefore easier to fit together.
- Continuing the "fit together" part, you may later find that you want to construct one big validator out of smaller ones. Perhaps you have a validator that checks that a person has specified a valid age and birth date, and want to build a validator out of this that also checks that the age is about right for the birth date. The `Monad` instance for `Either` will help here; for example:

  ```
  validatePerson p now = do
      age <- validateAge p
      date <- validateBirthdate p
      validateMatchingAgeAndDate age date now
  ```

  Or perhaps there are two ways for some value to validate properly and you want to allow either. Then `bigValidator v = option1 v <|> option2 v` is a cheap and cheerful way to combine the two ways of validating.

  As a side benefit, these methods of combining existing validators to make bigger ones will be instantly recognizable to other Haskellers.
- There is a very strong convention that `Nothing` is a failure. Using the opposite convention is not a *problem*, necessarily, but could be confusing to other contributors and potentially to yourself far in the future.

Comment: After using haskell for a few months I would like to say that I very strongly agree that this is the way to go.

Comment: Wouldn't `Either String User` be a better option?

Comment: @mb14 What is `User`, and why do you think it would be a better option than `()`?

Comment: I missed and thought the OP wanted to validate a User thus a function `validateUser :: User -> Error String User`. Is has the advantage of being to chain. However it doesn't enforce the validation function to not modify the input.

Answer (score 4):

What's an error message and what's an expected value is just a matter of you point of view. If you don't care about the `a` result value but do care about a possible error message, then that message is, as far as you're concerned, the value of interest. So, sure you can store it as a `Maybe String`.

In fact it's little different with `Either`. What I find backwards is that `Either` is usually perceived as “the possible-failure type”. Yes, its monad instance happens to work in the way that makes `Left` error-ish and `Right` success-ish, but ab initio `Either` is just a simple bifunctor expressing the sum of two types. Indeed, if Haskell had always had type operators, `Either a b` would probably be written `a + b` or `a || b`.

If you had an `Either String a` and want to “confiscate” the possible `a` value, the easiest way is to just `fmap (const ())` over it, resulting in an `Either String ()`, which is isomorphic to `Maybe String` but “looks more like the `String` has error character”, though as I said this is a bit silly.

To make it clear from the types that you're talking about error messages, I would use neither `Either` nor `Maybe` but [`Except String ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#g:1). Often, error values are caught over some other monad anyway, so you'd have e.g. `ExceptT String IO ()`.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using a custom type, isomorphic to `Maybe String`.

```
data Result = OK | Error String
```

or even

```
newtype Result = Result (Maybe String)
```

The latter makes it possible to avoid duplicating `Maybe` instances, since we can exploit [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=generalized#ghc-flag--XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving) to obtain the same effect

```
newtype Result = Result (Maybe String)
   deriving (Eq, Show) -- etc.
```

(Update: this might not be that useful, since most of such classes are standard ones, which can be automatically derived anyway. As Alexis King points out below, one can not make this into an applicative / alternative / monad, for instance, since the kinds do not match.)

The major downside now is having to use two constructors:

```
foo :: Result -> ...
foo (Result (Just x)) = ...
foo (Result (Nothing)) = ...
```

which is boring. One can go further and define [pattern synonyms](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=generalized#pattern-synonyms)

```
pattern OK      = Result Nothing
pattern Error x = Result (Just x)
```

so that we can then pretend we are using the first `data` definition shown above instead of the `newtype`.

```
foo :: Result -> ...
foo (Error x) = ...
foo OK        = ...
```

This might be reasonable or a bit overkill depending on whether you need those instances on the `Result` type. Even if you don't, it's not a very long approach to write, and I think many (most?) Haskellers would also be comfortable with the two required extensions.

For what it is worth, after reading the comments below, at the moment I believe that the first `data Result` approach is the best. It is simple, makes the point quite clearly, and if some class instances are needed, you probably want to define them manually (or automatically derive them, for standard `Prelude` classes).

Comment: With `Maybe`, validators can be trivially chained with `<|>`; with this custom type, it's not the case.

Comment: I just learned about a new type class, thanks for making the note about `<|>`. Would it be reasonable to make Result an instance of Alternative to get this behavior? Or is this the sort of thing where if I am implementing it myself, I am probably doing it wrong?

Comment: @jcolemang Yes, it would be reasonable. It is a bit unfortunate to have to duplicate already-present code. I will update with another alternative.

Comment: Combining validators with `<|>` is a perfect example of why you should define a new type `OK | Error a`, unless you want to think of a validator "succeeding" when it "successfully" finds something invalid about the input.

Comment: @ReidBarton If you considered a validator succeeding when it failed to find something invalid, wouldn't using `<|>` result in a valid result if only of the validators failed? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The point is the whole premise of using `<|>` to chain validators (assuming this means you want to check whether they all accept the input as valid) is backwards and confusing, since `a <|> b` is all about succeeding when either `a` or `b` does. Hence the name Alternative. The right way to chain validators is with `>>` (or whatever the trendy name for that operator is nowadays). That works for example with `Either String ()`.

Comment: This type cannot be a `Functor`, `Alternative`, `Applicative`, or `Monad`, as it has the wrong kind, so your example with GND is incorrect. That’s not so bad, though, since the instances wouldn’t really make sense—given that `Error` should short-circuit, there would be no place to hold the “success” value, and none of the usual typeclasses would be useful.

Comment: @AlexisKing Oh, right! Thanks. Now I do no longer believe the second approach is that useful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `Maybe String` is okay (its shape maps precisely onto the range of your function), but it won't compose nicely since all the useful instances take the opposite semantics for `Maybe`. `Either String ()` would be more useful (in terms of its monad/Applicative instances), and would also be clearer.

But there is a more appropriate "validation applicative" abstraction that would be worth exploring, which allows you to chain validations and accumulate errors (i.e. without short-circuiting on the first error). SOme flavors of implementation are in the [`validation` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation). From the docs:

```
>>> _Success # (+1) <*> _Success # 7 :: AccValidation String Int
AccSuccess 8

>>> _Failure # ["f1"] <*> _Success # 7 :: AccValidation [String] Int
AccFailure ["f1"]

>>> _Success # (+1) <*> _Failure # ["f2"] :: AccValidation [String] Int
AccFailure ["f2"]

>>> _Failure # ["f1"] <*> _Failure # ["f2"] :: AccValidation [String] Int
AccFailure ["f1","f2"]
```

Note that `AccValidation m` isn't a valid `Monad`. I experienced some minor pain when a composed parser / validation applicative suddenly needed to use bind.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** I do not believe that this is the best solution in general, but considering that this is for an assignment which only I will be working on and which does not include any requirements for good Haskell practices (or Haskell at all), this is the easiest solution for me. I borrowed some ideas from chi's answer.

---

I wanted the exact functionality of `Maybe`, but still wanted to avoid returning `Nothing` to indicate success and `Just msg` to indicate failure. To get around this I created what are really aliases to `Maybe` and its data constructors:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

type Result = Maybe
pattern AllGood = Nothing
pattern Fail x = Just x

-- example usage
isValidBorrower :: [String] -> Result String
isValidBorrower args
  | length args /= 3 = Fail "Wrong number of arguments"
  | otherwise = AllGood
```

This allows for the complete functionality of `Maybe` but the type checker will still show `MaybeFailure` if your types are incorrect and you don't see `Maybe String` in the type signature, which would be misleading.

The downside is that both of these functions still work:

```
foo :: Maybe String
foo = AllGood

bar :: Result String
bar = Nothing
```