# What’s the idiomatic type to represent multiple failure cases but only one success case?

Tags: haskell, idioms

The type `Maybe a` represents a computation that could fail, with the semantics that we don’t care about exactly *how* it failed. If the computation succeeds then any value of type `a` might be returned.

What about the inverse case, where the computation could fail for any number of reasons (and we want to preserve that information) but success doesn’t involve any information other than “yes, it succeeded”? I can think of two obvious ways to encode this kind of computation:

- `Maybe e`, where `Just e` represents a failure and `Nothing` represents a success. This is so contrary to the usual use of `Maybe` that I would be reluctant to use it.
- `Either e ()`, where `Left e` represents a failure and `Right ()` represents a success. This has the advantage of being explicit, but has the disadvantage of… being explicit. Writing `()` feels awkward, especially outside the context of a type signature.

Does Haskell have a more idiomatic way to represent “multiple failure cases but only one success case”?

Comment: You are looking for some kind of algebraic data type called `Result` defined by something like `data Result = Ok | Error String`. You can get fancier and use type variables for different kinds of errors and even add stuff to the `Ok` part. Elm has this type built in. Does Haskell? It might, look around. :)

Comment: Hmm, what about using `Either e ()` and creating a pattern synonym `pattern Success = Right ()`?

Comment: Your first bullet point reminds me of the idiomatic `err` variable in Go. It is typically re-shadowed every time you call a function that might fail, and after each result you must check: `if err != nil { //handle it }`

Comment: If you're working with monadic computation, then `ExceptT err m ()` would be my first instinct - an action that either succeeds with no result (success) or produces an error.

Comment: A computation that doesn't return any information other than "yes it succeeded" doesn't sound very useful outside of an IO action, and as far as I know the most idiomatic way to represent errors in that context is with exceptions, no? It really depends on what the function does, honestly.

Comment: @DarthFennec There are plenty of contexts other than `IO` where “yes it succeeded” might be desirable: `State`, `STM`, `Writer`...

Comment: `System.Exit` defines `data ExitCode = ExitSuccess | ExitFailure Int`, which is basically an exit-status-specific version of Ray Toal's `Result` suggestion. `ExitCode` also has an `Exception` instance, which implies the "standard" thing to do is define your own domain-specific type.

Comment: Very related, possibly dupe: [Should Maybe's be used to hold error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43236259/791604)

Comment: @DavidYoung That sounds like a decent solution to me (and it seems clear that there’s no single idiomatic solution that everyone already knows). Could you promote that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short way to go about this would be to use `Either e ()` along with the [pattern synonym](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=inline#pattern-synonyms)

```
pattern Success :: Either e ()  -- Explicit type signature not necessary
pattern Success = Right ()
```

You could also include some other things as well, if it improves readability, such as

```
type FailableWith e = Either e ()

pattern FailedWith :: e -> FailableWith e
pattern FailedWith x = Left x
```

Unlike `Maybe`, `Either` has the advantage of having all the existing machinery already in place: the `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad`, `Foldable`, `Traversable`, `Semigroup` and even `Ord` (`Left x < Right y` should always hold) instances will likely already behave exactly how you would want for error handling. Generally, for this particular situation, `Maybe` will tend to do the opposite of what you want (usually you want to continue on a success and stop after the first failure, which is the opposite of what most of the `Maybe` machinery will provide for this scenario).

Comment: The pattern synonyms is a bit point less as one will use only if he already knows the semantics behind the `Either e ()`. Itll be better using `Either e Success` with `data Success = Success`.

Comment: @mb14 Hmm, what makes that better? That just replaces `Right ()` with `Right Success` instead of just `Success`. Also, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. The reason for the pattern synonym and the type synonym would be to make things more clear to people who are *not* completely aware of the intent of the `Either e ()`.

Comment: Type synonyms doesn't provide guarantee (or safety or semantic as they can disappear) and add unnecessary level of indirection. I think `Eithe e ()` is clear enough, but `Eithe e Success` enforces a semantic if really needed.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the actual code it is actually difficult to understand what you mean by failure. If it's a pure function then I don't see what using `Maybe` would be a problem. I never really see `Nothing` as failure but just as it is : Nothing. Depending on the context , I  either return Nothing as well or, use a default value and carry on. I understand that it can be seen as a failure, but it more depends on the point  of view 
if the caller than the function itself.
Now, you want to represent a computation which can fails but returns nothing. If it is a pure function, that doesn't make sense. You function being pure, nothing has happened (no side effect) and you don't get a result. So in case of success, you actually computed nothing : that's not a success, that's nothing. ATHI If you fail, you've got a reason why it failed. That's no different from a simple check returning a `Maybe`.

For example you might need to check that a domain is not in a blacklist. For that you do a lookup in a list : Nothing means it's fine even though it means it's from your point of view and failure and need to stop your computation. The same code can be used to check your domain belongs to a white list. in that case Nothing is a failure : just depends on the context.

Now, if you are running a monadic action (like saving a file or something) it makes sense to return nothing but different failures can happened (disk full, path incorrect, etc). The standard signature for an IO which we don't care about the result is `IO ()`, so you can either go for `IO (Either e ())` (everybody will understand it) or go for `IO ()` and raises exception (if they are genuinely exceptional).

Comment: The Monad implementation for Maybe treats Nothing as a failure.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear from the question how the computation might fail.

If it is something like a compiler, which might produce a lot of error messages (rather than halting on the first one) then you want something like:

```
type MyResult a = Either [Error] a
```

which either succeeds with a result or fails with a list of reasons.

On the other hand if you have a non-deterministic computation where each variation might succeed or fail then you want something more like:

```
type MyResult a = [Either Error a]
```

Then search the list of results. If you find a Right then return it, otherwise assemble the list of Lefts.